# Two queries when Joined together adds more records and duplicates records

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two queries. First Query: Raw data for the clock in. Second Query: Raw data for the clock out. When i combined the two queries together i get duplicated records. On my Raw Check in there are only 2 records and for my clock out query there are 6 records. When I combine the two Queries together i get the total of 12 records with a lot of duplicated entries on both sides.

**First Query Code:**

```
SELECT USERINFO.Badgenumber, USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]) AS DateValue, TimeValue([Time]) AS TimeValue, acc_monitor_log.device_name, Dev.ClockINOut
FROM (Dev INNER JOIN acc_monitor_log ON Dev.DeviceName = acc_monitor_log.device_name) INNER JOIN USERINFO ON acc_monitor_log.pin = USERINFO.Badgenumber
WHERE (((USERINFO.name) Is Null Or (USERINFO.name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Query].[NameQ] & "*") AND ((DateValue([Time]))>=[Forms]![Query]![StartDateQ] And (DateValue([Time]))<=[Forms]![Query]![EndDateQ]) AND ((TimeValue([Time]))>=[Forms]![Query]![StartTimeQ] And (TimeValue([Time]))<=[Forms]![Query]![EndTimeQ]) AND ((Dev.ClockINOut)="Clock In"))
ORDER BY USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]);
```

[image: rawdatainquery]

**Second Query Code:**

```
SELECT USERINFO.Badgenumber, USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]) AS DateValue, TimeValue([Time]) AS TimeValue, acc_monitor_log.device_name, Dev.ClockINOut
FROM (Dev INNER JOIN acc_monitor_log ON Dev.DeviceName = acc_monitor_log.device_name) INNER JOIN USERINFO ON acc_monitor_log.pin = USERINFO.Badgenumber
WHERE (((USERINFO.name) Is Null Or (USERINFO.name) Like "*" & Forms!Query.NameQ & "*") And ((DateValue([Time]))>=Forms!Query!StartDateQ And (DateValue([Time]))<=Forms!Query!EndDateQ) And ((TimeValue([Time]))>=Forms!Query!StartTimeQ And (TimeValue([Time]))<=Forms!Query!EndTimeQ) And ((Dev.ClockINOut)="Clock Out"))
ORDER BY USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]);
```

[image: rawdataoutquery]

**And the Combined Query of the two above queries:**

```
SELECT RQOut.Badgenumber, RQOut.name, RQOut.DateValue, RQOut.TimeValue, RQOut.ClockINOut, RQIn.TimeValue, RQIn.device_name, RQIn.ClockINOut, [RQIn].[TimeValue]-[RQOut].[TimeValue] AS Timess
FROM RQOut INNER JOIN RQIn ON (RQOut.Badgenumber = RQIn.Badgenumber) AND (RQOut.name = RQIn.name) AND (RQOut.DateValue = RQIn.DateValue)
WHERE (((RQOut.name) Is Null Or (RQOut.name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Query].[NameQ] & "*") AND ((RQOut.DateValue)>=[Forms]![Query]![StartDateQ] And (RQOut.DateValue)<=[Forms]![Query]![EndDateQ]) AND ((RQOut.TimeValue)>=[Forms]![Query]![StartTimeQ] And (RQOut.TimeValue)<=[Forms]![Query]![EndTimeQ]))
ORDER BY RQOut.TimeValue, RQIn.TimeValue;
```

[image: combinedqueries]

Please can anyone tell me why i am getting this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a form called "Query"? What are you trying to do with this`DateValue([Time]) ` are you getting the Datevalue from a field called `Time` or are you trying to call the `Time` function? Do you have fields called `Name` and `DateValue` too?

Comment: Yes i got a form named Query. Runs all my queries from. Depending on Name and Date and time. I had a table called acc_monitor_log which was imported from from another database. Date and Times were joined by date function. I create a new query called Raw query which i made the date and times in their own rows. From there i created 2 New queries to display only the clock in data and the clock out data. Now what i want to do join the two queries together and calculate the times.

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN between two data sets returns records from both data sets where the fields match. If one record in the first data set matched 10 records (say) in the second dataset, it returns 10 records.

This is effectively the process the inner join is following in your last query: It will look at record 1 of RQin, then search for matching records in RQout. For the fields you asked to match up, ALL of the records in RQOut will be returned, because the fields you joined on match up for ALL the records. It then does the same for record 2 in RQIn, and again it matches with ALL the records on RQOut. This means you get 2 x 6 = 12 records returned.

Comment: When using an outer join, regardless if i use a left or a right outer join I'm getting returned #error where the values should be.

Comment: My guess is that because you are using an OUTER JOIN you will get some Null values, and when you try and calculate the time difference, this gives an error. HOWEVER, I reckon that changing the join type alone is not going to fix your issue. You need to JOIN on fields that relate each check in to the corresponding check out. I would suggest putting each attendance of a member as a record in one table, which has fields for check-in check out times.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm working linked table from another access database. I'm using a machine, acc_monitor_log, USERINFO. From these tables i create my own table call dev where you enter the the device name and it will select if the device is = to clock in or out. So i could use clock in and clock out instead of knowing what the device is be called. the userinfo contains the user info Machines is the device name with the ip address. Now the log that contains the recorded time is in a single field called time. That is why i was using a query. A table would of been so much easier.